# Separate SCSS and HTML in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, inline-styles

In the Angular2 project I need to apply some css to the button.
I want to add a class in .html and describe all style attributes in .scss file but unfortunately this element "doesn't" see the class.
However as soon as I add the same style as inline style in the .html file - everything works correctly.

I want to replace this code (from the snippet below, 5th line)
`[ngStyle]="{ position: 'absolute', 'z-index': '10', right: '0' }"`

by this `class="test-class"`
And use the data for the `test-class` from the .scss file.

The link to the stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-avvwha?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

.html

```
 <div>
  <gridster [options]="options">
    <gridster-item [item]="item" *ngFor="let item of dashboard">
      <div
        [ngStyle]="{ position: 'absolute', 'z-index': '10', right: '0' }"
      >
        <button mat-mini-fab>
          <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
      <ng-container>
        <div class="outline">
          <div class="header">
            <div class="header-text">Text</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </gridster-item>
  </gridster>
</div>
```

.scss

```
.test-class {
  position: 'absolute';
  z-index: 10;
  right: 0;
}
```

Also maybe there is any other option to remove style from .html file and I overlooked it.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add test-class to your element:

```
<div class="test-class">
  <button mat-mini-fab>
    <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
  </button>
</div>
```

Second is your style should just be `absolute`, not `'absolute'`:

```
.test-class {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  right: 0;
}
```

See here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-z8wfaj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss

Answer (score 1):

In Scss file .. you put position: 'absolute'. abosulte should not be a string.

position: absolute;

Comment: Thank you! Totally overlooked it